# Excel-VBA, Tree simulation with 2 variables

Tags: vba, excel, tree, simulation

I am trying to model a population birth rate in a city where after every year, T+0 to T+n, where n is the number of nodes. So every +1 year, there could either be 101% of the population, 100% or 99% of the population remaining in the city.

To add to the complexity, the number of people in the city has to be dynamic at any time. So for example we know the path in the 5th year where we get +1% of population every year. so at 5th year we should have (1.01)^5 people. However, since this city is dynamic, there could be people leaving or entering the city, so manual adjustments to the city population has be to catered for.

E.G. At 5th year, 5000 left the city to another place. So the spreadsheet has to be dynamic enough to adjust the 5th level node from (1.01)^5 to (1.01)^5 - 5000. And the 6th node carries on from there.... branching out again.

Not sure if i explained this clearly enough. But this seems to be really hard to code with my amateur vba skills. Is this possible?

I thought about it and faced the following problems, was wondering if this makes sense or if its even doable:

1) The row insertion to build a "tree" is computationally expensive, no way around it. While this is fine for a small number of nodes, a bigger tree would just take hours for a click of the macro! ( i intend to use this up to 11/12 nodes, which takes way too long!) 
- Is it possible to build a solution where macro calculations uses the same "tree" once it has been generated once, rather than to regenerate the tree every single click. i.e. to spilt up the processes, i would run a tree with 12 node at the start. And afterwhich the tweaking of the input values simply generates values that shows itself up in the tree, rather than cleaning the sheets and inserting new rows again.

2) Let me illustrate whats going on here in the best way i can. 
The initial value of 100, which was used for this test, will be replaced by a formula. Lets call this formula, (A*B*Sqrt(C) + 6/X), where A, B, are constants and X is the initial % move input in the sheet which the tree branches are based off. C is the tricky bit - this is assumed to be constant until a manual intervention comes in.

Lets for a moment assume a simple tree model, with 5 nodes - giving the following structure. 1, 3, 9, 27, 81 ,243 ... 3^n, where n is the number of nodes.
Running this formula with an initial input of 2%, whereby X = 2%.
We get a nice small tree with values at this point of time. 
I am trying to build a more dynamic tree here, whereby i can step in for e.g. on the 2nd value of node 3, adjust the input for C and see how the dependant nodes changes. All without affecting the previously assumed C value on nodes 1 & 2, and nodes not directly affected by the forward path of this particular value.

So in this picture below, only the blue paths should be affected by the new C value input. Is this something possible? I am so stuck...

[image]

```
    Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
Dim startvalue As Double, levels As Integer, levelchange As Double
Dim counterforlevel As Double, j As Long, i As Long, k As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
startvalue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
levels = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
levelchange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c2")
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Cells.ClearContents
Range("A1") = startvalue
For j = 2 To levels
  counterforlevel = 3 ^ (j - 2)
    For k = Cells(Rows.Count, j - 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If k Mod 10 = 0 Then Application.StatusBar = "Level: " & j & Space(5) & "Processing " & Format(1 - k / counterforlevel, "#0.0%")
        If Cells(k, j - 1) <> "" Then
            Rows(k + 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
            Cells(k + 1, j).Formula = "=" & Cells(k, j - 1).Address(False, False) & "*" & Format(1 - levelchange, "0%")
            Cells(k, j).Formula = "=" & Cells(k, j - 1).Address(False, False)
            Rows(k).Insert shift:=xlDown
            Cells(k, j).Formula = "=" & Cells(k + 1, j - 1).Address(False, False) & "*" & Format(1 + levelchange, "0%")
        End If
        DoEvents
    Next k
Next j
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Comment: i am trying to understand what you are trying to do. is there a final solution value? is it a tree building exercise?  ... you could just use cell formulas for the whole thing. every one of the filled cells in your example would have a formula. manual adjustments could be entered into cells like C14 for 3rd node or C12 for 4th node, or manual adjustments could be entered into top row (move everything downward)

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for your comments.

I am trying to run a simulation here, thus the need to be dynamic. I.e. what are the possible outcomes if 2nd value at 5th node suddenly has an influx of 5000 people, or if disease factor, C changes by 20%. etc. To be able to see what happens to the "right side" of the tree and to dynamically adjust any further inputs (maybe reduce the disease factor after its cured etc ), to see how the pop change would be like after nth node.

In short, I want values. But also the path and scenarios which should be adjustable manually by  bumping the formula.

Comment: @jsotola Wouldnt using manual adjustments in that sense affect the tree outcomes? i.e. if i adjust the 2nd value of 3rd node, the rest of the tree shouldnt change, only the dependants on the right side of it.

Comment: you want C15 to influence D15, E14,E15,E16 only (and child nodes of these) ?

Comment: why should the rest of the tree be unchanged? why is the +- 1% unaffected by any manual adjustment? if, at C15, a nuclear explosion kills everyone. why would you still want values in D12 and D18?

Comment: it seems to me that you are trying to come up with a simulation that is more like a line graph with two lines. like this one http://www.library.illinois.edu/systems/jpgraph/docs/html/img/example17.png (consider only the green area) top line is "always +1%" and bottom line of green area is "always -1%". the bump at X9 is an influx

Comment: @jsotola Because what happens at Node 3, tends to be a probability function rather than a definite scenario. i.e. there is gonna be a lot more outcomes/possible paths as the node increases. 

The line graph wouldnt work so well as the function i might be interested in could be : +1% for first 2 years(nodes), - 2% for next 2 years,disease sets in, affecting constant C.. or some migration influx, followed by a normal pop growth again of 5% etc. 

I am trying to build something where i can make dynamic assumptions and yet compare with the rest if the scenario didnt occur. if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i sort of understand what you are trying to do. it is still unclear how you intend to use the data in the last node (how are you going to visualize the results)

maybe you need to use something like this

```
                110   121   132   143   154     10% increase per year
          100   100   100   100   100   100     these 3 rows are a reference dataset
                 90    81    73    66    59     10% decline per year    



               +10%  +10%  +10%  +10%  +10%     this can be manually adjusted
upper bound     110   125   136   147   158
          100   100   105   105   105   105     scenario
lower bound      90    86    76    69    62
               -10%  -10%  -10%  -10%  -10%   
manual adjust  +5                 


have multiple scenarios on worksheet

could use VBA to fill in the percentage values and transfer the result into another worksheet
```